# PySpark - Losing String values when Creating Key Value Pairs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I need to create key value pairs for each row within the dataframe / RDD. That is every person will become a key for each row and their associated transaction is a list which becomes the value.

I have the following example to illustrate my issue:

```python
a = [
    ('Bob', 562,"Food", "12 May 2018"),
    ('Bob',880,"Food","01 June 2018"),
    ('Bob',380,'Household'," 16 June 2018"),
    ('Sue',85,'Household'," 16 July 2018"),
    ('Sue',963,'Household'," 16 Sept 2018")
] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ["Person", "Amount","Budget", "Date"])
```

Then, I create a function to do the key value pair for each row

```python
def make_keys_and_value(row):
    """ Convert the dataframe rows into key value pairs

    """
    return (row["Person"], [[row["Amount"], row["Budget"],
                                 row["Date"]]])
person_summarries_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row : make_keys_and_value(row))
```

However when I want to show the results, `Budget` and `Date` becomes nulls. I think this is due to the fact that they are string values.

```python
person_summarries_rdd.toDF().show(5,False)
+---+-------------------------------+
|_1 |_2                             |
+---+-------------------------------+
|Bob|[WrappedArray(562, null, null)]|
|Bob|[WrappedArray(880, null, null)]|
|Bob|[WrappedArray(380, null, null)]|
|Sue|[WrappedArray(85, null, null)] |
|Sue|[WrappedArray(963, null, null)]|
+---+-------------------------------+
```

I need to preserve the values of strings while still using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to serialize to `rdd`. You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.struct()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct):

```python
import pyspark.sql.function as f
df.withColumn('values', f.struct(f.col('Amount'), f.col('Budget'), f.col('Date')))\
    .select('Person', 'values').show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----------------------------+
#|Person|values                       |
#+------+-----------------------------+
#|Bob   |[562,Food,12 May 2018]       |
#|Bob   |[880,Food,01 June 2018]      |
#|Bob   |[380,Household, 16 June 2018]|
#|Sue   |[85,Household, 16 July 2018] |
#|Sue   |[963,Household, 16 Sept 2018]|
#+------+-----------------------------+
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```python
array_columns = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'Person']
df.withColumn('values', f.struct(*[f.col(c) for c in array_columns]))\
    .select('Person', 'values').show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----------------------------+
#|Person|values                       |
#+------+-----------------------------+
#|Bob   |[562,Food,12 May 2018]       |
#|Bob   |[880,Food,01 June 2018]      |
#|Bob   |[380,Household, 16 June 2018]|
#|Sue   |[85,Household, 16 July 2018] |
#|Sue   |[963,Household, 16 Sept 2018]|
#+------+-----------------------------+
```

---

Your code doesn't work because you can't have mixed types in a `WrappedArray()`. Spark is inferring the type from the first item (`Amount`).

You could either cast `Amount` to a `str`:

```python
def make_keys_and_value(row):
    """ Convert the dataframe rows into key value pairs

    """
    return (row["Person"], [[str(row["Amount"]), row["Budget"],
                                 row["Date"]]])
person_summarries_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row : make_keys_and_value(row))
person_summarries_rdd.toDF().show(truncate=False)
#+---+---------------------------------------------+
#|_1 |_2                                           |
#+---+---------------------------------------------+
#|Bob|[WrappedArray(562, Food, 12 May 2018)]       |
#|Bob|[WrappedArray(880, Food, 01 June 2018)]      |
#|Bob|[WrappedArray(380, Household,  16 June 2018)]|
#|Sue|[WrappedArray(85, Household,  16 July 2018)] |
#|Sue|[WrappedArray(963, Household,  16 Sept 2018)]|
#+---+---------------------------------------------+
```

Or use a `tuple` instead of a `list`:

```python
def make_keys_and_value(row):
    """ Convert the dataframe rows into key value pairs

    """
    return (row["Person"], ((row["Amount"]), row["Budget"],
                                 row["Date"]))
person_summarries_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row : make_keys_and_value(row))
#+---+-----------------------------+
#|_1 |_2                           |
#+---+-----------------------------+
#|Bob|[562,Food,12 May 2018]       |
#|Bob|[880,Food,01 June 2018]      |
#|Bob|[380,Household, 16 June 2018]|
#|Sue|[85,Household, 16 July 2018] |
#|Sue|[963,Household, 16 Sept 2018]|
#+---+-----------------------------+
```

Here I took out the nested `[]`, but you could easily add it back in if you prefer the output to look like `[[562,Food,12 May 2018]]` instead of `[562,Food,12 May 2018]`.

---

Another option is to create a map using [`pyspark.sql.functions.create_map()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map):

```python
df.withColumn(
    'values',
    f.create_map(
        *reduce(
            list.__add__,
            [[f.lit(c), f.col(c)] for c in array_columns]
        )
    )
).select('Person', 'values').show(truncate=False)
#+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
#|Person|values                                                        |
#+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
#|Bob   |Map(Amount -> 562, Budget -> Food, Date -> 12 May 2018)       |
#|Bob   |Map(Amount -> 880, Budget -> Food, Date -> 01 June 2018)      |
#|Bob   |Map(Amount -> 380, Budget -> Household, Date ->  16 June 2018)|
#|Sue   |Map(Amount -> 85, Budget -> Household, Date ->  16 July 2018) |
#|Sue   |Map(Amount -> 963, Budget -> Household, Date ->  16 Sept 2018)|
#+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or if perhaps you wanted to go directly to a mapping of `Person->array`:

```python
df.withColumn('values', f.struct(*[f.col(c) for c in array_columns]))\
    .withColumn('map',f.create_map(f.col('Person'), f.col('values')))\
    .select('map')\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------------------------+
#|map                                      |
#+-----------------------------------------+
#|Map(Bob -> [562,Food,12 May 2018])       |
#|Map(Bob -> [880,Food,01 June 2018])      |
#|Map(Bob -> [380,Household, 16 June 2018])|
#|Map(Sue -> [85,Household, 16 July 2018]) |
#|Map(Sue -> [963,Household, 16 Sept 2018])|
#+-----------------------------------------+
```